# Create multiple file in PHP using foreach loop for array created using file() function

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops, foreach

I am trying to create multiple files in PHP using a foreach loop. The foreach loop reads the contents of an array, which is formed using file() function from a text(.txt) file. The loop is supposed to create a [.php] file with EACH of the value in the array, but it is creating the file for ONLY the LAST value in the array.

```
<?php
$user_list=file('users.txt');
$n=0;
foreach ($user_list as $user[$n]) {
if(!file_exists("Users/".$_POST[username]."-".$user[$n].".php")){
$file_c=fopen("Users/".$_POST[username]."-".$user[$n].".php", 'a+'); 
fwrite($file_c,"Content");  
}
$n++;
} 
?>
```

Comment: whats the output of $user_list?

Comment: Rafael Shkembi the output is correct, exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with multiple `fwrite()`, need to be close file handler by `fclose()` after writing file was completed:

```
<?php
    $user_list=file('users.txt');

    foreach ($user_list as $user) {
        if(!file_exists("Users/".$_POST[username]."-".trim($user).".php")){
            $file_c=fopen("Users/".$_POST[username]."-".trim($user).".php", 'a'); 
            fwrite($file_c,"Content");
            fclose($file_c);
        }

    } 
?>
```

Comment: I used fclose() after you said, still only the LAST value is printed.

Comment: I removed the counter($n) but that still didn't help. It even created problem when I was printing [hyperlinks]. Still only the last value's file is created.

Comment: User `a` instead of `a+` parameter of `fopen()`

Comment: I used the parameters 'a' , 'x' and 'w' as well, still no good. :(

Comment: how `$user_list=file('users.txt');` return array? It's string! What's content of **users.txt** file?

Comment: It's ok Bro! My program now works. I just used trim() function in $user

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as you are reading from `text file`, there have a lot of chance of adding a `space` suffixed with the data in the array., i used `trim()` method and it worked fine for me, A suggestion, use `file_exists ()` function to check if directory exists.  the following code worked for me i hard coded the user name .

```
<?php
    $user_list=file('users.txt');
    $username = 'sdcds';

    foreach ($user_list as $user) {
        if(!file_exists('Users/'.$username."-".trim($user).".php")){

            $file_c = fopen('Users/'.$username."-".trim($user).".php", 'a+'); 
            fwrite($file_c,"Content");
            fclose($file_c);
        }

    } 
?>
```

Comment: @Mrigank Pawagi try this once

Comment: Thanks a lot bro..! I used trim and now ALL the files are created. Thanks a lot for your help. Just check out mrigankpawagi.github.io   one my project is finished!